# How to use function move_uploaded_file correctly in php

Tags: php

I'm having a problem using move_uploaded_file() function to upload files. I wanted the files to be uploaded on the "upload" directory but I can't seem to figure out how to as the "upload" directory is always empty whenever I try to execute these codes. Can you please help me? Thank you.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $file = $_FILES['file'];

    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $fileTmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];

    $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
    $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

    $allowed = array('jpg','jpeg','png','pdf','docx','doc','xlsx','ppt','pptx');

if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)){
    if ($fileError === 0){
        if ($fileSize < 1000000) {
            $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$fileActualExt;
            $fileDestination = 'uploads/ ';
            $fileTarget = $fileDestination . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $fileDestination);
        }

    } else {
        echo "There was an error uploading your file!";
    } else {
        echo "You cannot upload files of this type!";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What the ....  **} else {
       
    } else {
        
    }** ?

Comment: `'uploads/ '` contains a space, I'd remove that. You also might want to use `$fileTarget ` instead of `$fileDestination`. Check permissions too. Also, what is `$fileNameNew` for?

Comment: 1) File extensions can be easily faked. `image.jpeg` can be quite happily a PHP file. Be careful with this

Comment: 2) Your file destination string (`$fileTarget` / `$fileDestination`) is relative to your current PHP working directory, so your upload folder needs to be a child folder of your current working directory (usually the directory the script is in). Use `getcwd()` to check.

Comment: 3 )You should also be using [`is_uploaded_file`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php) and following the [PHP tutorial](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

Comment: 4) You should be checking your logs for errors, they will help you get this working!!

Answer (score 0):

Need to pass new upload file name and give permission to upload folder.

Try with below solution.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $fileDestination.$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$fileTarget` instead of `$fileDestination` at the second argument of [move_uploaded_file()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php):

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $fileTarget);
```

and don't forget to remove space from `'uploads/ '` in `$fileDestination`;

Also, you have a very weird `if statement`, it can't has the second `else` condition, I mean  it can't has view like **if (){ } else { } else { }**. Fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check it - [Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php#refsect1-function.move-uploaded-file-examples)

> Example #3 Uploading array of files

```
$uploads_dir = '/uploads';
foreach ($_FILES["file"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        // basename() may prevent filesystem traversal attacks;
        // further validation/sanitation of the filename may be appropriate
        $name = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"][$key]);
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to rename the uploaded file (because of the $fileNameNew variable). So I guess you need create $fileTarget variable like this:

```
$fileNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$fileActualExt;
$fileDestination = 'uploads/ ';
$fileTarget = $fileDestination . $fileNameNew;
```

And then use it ($fileTarget) as the argument of the move_uploaded_file function, like this:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $fileTarget);
```

Also, it will be cool if you can simplify your code by clearing the if/else statements. See if you can write something like this:

```
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    exit('Nothing to perform');
}

$file = $_FILES['file'];
$fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$fileTmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];
$fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];

$fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
$fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

$allowed = array('jpg','jpeg','png','pdf','docx','doc','xlsx','ppt','pptx');

if ($fileError !== 0) {
    exit('There was an error uploading your file!');
}

if (!in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)) {
    exit('You cannot upload files of this type!');
}

if ($fileSize > 1000000) {
    exit('The file is too large');
}

$fileNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$fileActualExt;
$fileDestination = 'uploads/ ';
$fileTarget = $fileDestination . $fileNameNew;

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $fileTarget);
```